# Prevent UINavigationBar animation in custom container

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

I followed this guide [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) to make a container that would handle login/logout in the app.

Children view controllers are: UINavigationController for login, and UITabBarController for the rest of the app:

[image: diagram]

My problem is that UINavigationBar animates strangely, and I want to prevent its animation:

[image: transition]

The animation code is basically this ([full project code here](https://github.com/paiv/logintotabs)):

```
    let current = childViewControllers.first
    current?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

    child.securityContainer = self
    addChildViewController(child)

        child.view.frame = newChildOriginFrame

        UIView.transitionWithView(view, duration: 0.3, options: [], animations: {

            child.view.frame = newChildTargetFrame
            current?.view.frame = oldChildTargetFrame

            self.view.addSubview(child.view)

        }, completion: { _ in

            child.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            current?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            current?.removeFromParentViewController()
            current?.securityContainer = nil
        })
```

How can I prevent animation of UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by moving `addSubview` outside animations block:

```
let current = childViewControllers.first
current?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

child.securityContainer = self
addChildViewController(child)

    child.view.frame = newChildOriginFrame

    view.addSubview(child.view)

    UIView.transitionWithView(view, duration: 0.3, options: [], animations: {

        child.view.frame = newChildTargetFrame
        current?.view.frame = oldChildTargetFrame

    }, completion: { _ in

        child.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        current?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        current?.removeFromParentViewController()
        current?.securityContainer = nil
    })
```

([full project source code](https://github.com/paiv/logintotabs))